# Is it ok to use @Component for any utitliy class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have got a Class that converts Entity to DTO, class is mainly Mapper `ConfigurableMapper` from Orika packages.  I have annotated the mapper class with `@Component` and Autowired it any class to convert from DTO to Mapper.  This can be achieved without `@Component` and Autowiring.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: This is generally okay, but you shouldn't be needing to do this translation in more than one or maybe two places. (MapStruct offers the option of generating mappers with `@Component` attached already.)

Comment: I'd say it's ok to use injection on utility classes where you need an instance, e.g. for inheritance reasons or to maintain state. If the class just has a bunch of static methods I'd suggest just using those without any injection. One thing you should keep in mind though is the scope of those instances, i.e. if the instance can't be used concurrently or can't reasonably be reused you should make sure to get a new instance every time you need to use that class (or at least get a separate instance per thread).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a ConverterFactory for Conversion

Baeldung wrote an article about it under:
[spring-type-conversions](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions)
For some Reference:
[docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html)
An even more specific Implementation also from Baeldung:
[Entity To DTO Conversion for a Spring REST API](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application)

I'm not sure if it is necessary to annotate @Component to helper/utility classes. As long as they don't need to be instantiated from spring as a bean you can delete the annotation.